# No power to garbage disposal, unfamiliar duplex outlet

Tags: wiring, kitchen-sink, garbage-disposal

A couple of problems in my question.  Originally, the garbage disposal (GD) functioned.

It is in the kitchen of a townhome plugged in under the sink.  There is a single outlet with a top and bottom receptacle.  Plugged into the top receptacle, it doesn't run. If I plug the disposal in the bottom receptacle  it runs continuously.  It is normally controlled by a switch which is in the wall. The box on the wall has two switches in it.  One of the switch is to the garbage disposal as mentioned and the other  to at least an overhead light.  That light is working fine, controlled by its switch.

On the GD switch, there is no voltage across terminals regardless of switch position.

Examining the outlet,  there is a top and bottom receptacle.  The top has a black and white line connected to either side via those push-in holes.  Here is the strange part: The bottom receptacle has a single wire.  I'm sorry I forgot if it was black or white.  Further, BOTH tabs between the outlets are broken off.  Does this seem correct?  It doesn't to me.

I should have grabbed pictures, but I'm hoping that this is a standard configuration, and the wiring mistake will be obvious to you (but certainly isn't to me).  I thought maybe the two receptacles shared common and the tab shouldn't be removed, and the two hots should have the tab removed.  With both tabs removed, it seems incorrect...yet as I say the bottom receptacle  is powered.

Can you say how the wiring is incorrect and guess what might have happened?  I can’t say if the wiring has always been the way it is now or if someone made changes.  The only thing I know if that it worked initially.

As a side question, I don't mind replacing the outlet with a GFCI, but with one switched and one not switched, should I consider having that done?  That said I know its more expensive, but I'd be willing to switch out the breaker.

Comment: Have you looked everywhere for a tripped gfci (garage, outside, bathrooms...) and have you manually flipped all the breakers from on to off to on? (Sometimes breakers trip without looking tripped.)

Comment: Only the tab on the hot(black) side should be broken off.  One black should be always hot, and the second from the switch is a switched hot.  Off hand if it worked and just stopped working, I would suspect the push in connections.  Both tabs being broken off and only one wire(white?) on one side is odd.  Pictures of the outlet and switch with the wires connected, turn off the breaker, will help.

Comment: @Traveler  With both tabs broken off, OP needs two wires on each side.  OP only has one wire on one side.

Comment: Outlets do burn out.  IIRC GD outlets are supposed to be GF protected, whether at the outlet or the breaker—you're sure the breaker isn't already GFCI?